# D3JS V4 Zoomable line chart with circle points and tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

My requirement is to draw a graph using the data in format as follows array of array. Which is converted to array of objects to used in graph.

with 100 000 data.
So following features needed:

1. Zoomable - This feature is implemented in the code below.
2. Tooltip on hover -
   Unable to set tooltip on hover. How can I do this?
3. Circle once zoom section showing less than 100 records - Can find the extent but failing to set circle on the zoomed section.
4. Line break on x-axis date time to accommodate more data - Is there any way to set html record in x axis with formatted data or using \n or word break etc?

My code is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Load d3.js -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script src="generator.js"></script>
<script src="data-set.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-tip/0.9.1/d3-tip.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-a+/SD0dbGeXTN4AA5F1dDZqsPvXKKyS1bvU2z5ElpKNJ4xQlOMUs/1+suA+j+kj5nAAya+VmT5HUKZmazluxVQ=="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz">
</div>


<script>

    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var margin = { top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50 };

    var height = window.innerHeight / 2;
    var width = window.innerWidth / 2;
    var tooltip = { width: 100, height: 100, x: 10, y: -30 };

    // append the svg object to the body of the page
    var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform",
            "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")


    svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", -40)
        .attr("dy", ".4em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("CPU Utilization (In Percentage)");

    svg.append("text")
        .attr("y", (height + 40))
        .attr("x", (width / 2))
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Date Time");


    var data = data_set.map((d) => {
        return { "date": d[0], "data": d[1] }
    });
    console.log(data);
    setChart(data);
    // Now I can use this dataset:
    function setChart(data) {

        // Add X axis --> it is a date format
        var x = d3.scaleTime()
            .domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return new Date(d.date); }))
            .range([0, width]);
        xAxis = svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
                .ticks(width / 120)
                .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d %H:%I")))


        // Add Y axis
        var y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return +d.data; })])
            .range([height, 0]);
        yAxis = svg.append("g")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y));


        // Add a clipPath: everything out of this area won't be drawn.
        var clip = svg.append("defs").append("svg:clipPath")
            .attr("id", "clip")
            .append("svg:rect")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", 0);

        // Add brushing
        var brush = d3.brushX()                   // Add the brush feature using the d3.brush function
            .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])  // initialise the brush area: start at 0,0 and finishes at width,height: it means I select the whole graph area
            .on("end", updateChart)               // Each time the brush selection changes, trigger the 'updateChart' function

        // Create the line variable: where both the line and the brush take place
        var line = svg.append('g')
            .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
        var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
            .attr("class", "tooltip")
            .style("opacity", 0);
        // Add the line
        var chart = line.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("class", "line")  // I add the class line to be able to modify this line later on.
            .attr("fill", "none")

            .attr("stroke", "#90c1fe")
            .attr("stroke-width", 1)
            .attr("d", d3.line()
                .x(function (d) { return x(new Date(d.date)) })
                .y(function (d) { return y(d.data) })
            )


        svg.selectAll("myCircles").data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("fill", "#90c1fe")
            .attr("stroke", "none")
            .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.date) })
            .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.data) })
            .attr("r", 1)

        console.log(data);
        // Add the brushing
        line.append("g")
            .attr("class", "brush")
            .call(brush);

        // A function that set idleTimeOut to null
        var idleTimeout
        function idled() { idleTimeout = null; }
        // A function that update the chart for given boundaries
        function updateChart() {
            // What are the selected boundaries?
            extent = d3.event.selection

            if (extent && extent[1] - extent[0] < 100) {

            }
            // If no selection, back to initial coordinate. Otherwise, update X axis domain
            if (!extent) {
                if (!idleTimeout) return idleTimeout = setTimeout(idled, 350); // This allows to wait a little bit
                x.domain([4, 8])
            } else {
                x.domain([x.invert(extent[0]), x.invert(extent[1])])
                line.select(".brush").call(brush.move, null) // This remove the grey brush area as soon as the selection has been done
            }

            // Update axis and line position
            xAxis.transition().duration(2000).call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(width / 120).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))

            line.select('.line')
                .transition()
                .duration(2000)
                .attr("d", d3.line()
                    .x(function (d) { return x(d.date) })
                    .y(function (d) { return y(d.data) })
                )



        }


        // If user double click, reinitialize the chart
        svg.on("dblclick", function () {
            resetChart();
        });


        function resetChart() {
            x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.date; }))
            xAxis.transition().duration(2000)
                .call(d3.axisBottom(x)

                    .ticks(width / 120)
                    // .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d %H:%I")));
                    .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d %H:%I")))

            line
                .select('.line')
                .transition().duration(2000)
                .attr("d", d3.line()
                    .x(function (d) { return x(d.date) })
                    .y(function (d) { return y(d.data) })
                )

        }


    };




</script>
```